# Running a Tomcat embedded Java app

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to build and run a minimal Java app with embedded Tomcat but I'm having some difficulties (as outlined at the bottom).

I'm trying to keep the configuration to a minimum, so if a value doesn't need to be set because the default value is already the required value, or a dependency already includes another dependency, then I won't set it.  Which I'm basically figuring out by running and responding to errors.

My directory structure is as follows (I'm confused with what the standard data structure is so I went with Maven as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)).

[image: Directory Structure]

I use a maven project with the following `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.24</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- includes core, el, jasper, annotations-api -->
            <!-- core includes juli logging -->
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    </build>
</project>
```

My `Main` class is the following

```
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.File;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException, ServletException {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8080);
        tomcat.addWebapp("", new File("src/main/webapp").getAbsolutePath());
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

My `web.xml` simply points to the servlet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Servlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Just with this configuration, I am able to run a Tomcat Server, display JSP pages with JSTL code, and run the WebServlet.

When I start the application, I get the following output which all looks good.

```
Dec 28, 2017 12:31:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 28, 2017 12:31:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 28, 2017 12:31:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Dec 28, 2017 12:31:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.24
Dec 28, 2017 12:31:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Dec 28, 2017 12:31:53 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 28, 2017 12:31:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

The problems I'm having are as follows:

1. How do you configure logging?  I have tried to include a
   logging.properties file in resources, as well as WEB-INF/classes and
   even /lib, /config, /, but I can't seem to get it to work.
2. How do you change to using Log4J? The maven `tomcat-embed-jasper`
   dependency includes `juli` which I tried to add `<exclude>` to the
   dependency but it didnt remove it.
3. Do I have to declare every `serlvet-mapping` in `web.xml` or is there another way (NOT using Spring framework) to have Tomcat recognise them?

Comment: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: Well (1) and (2) are related and what I originally wanted to know.  Seems since the Subject covers question (3) that it seems sensible to leave it, but (4) I agree is off-topic and I shall remove it.